# 127.0.0.1:54282 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) on laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eof, laravel-5.4

I have a fresh install of laravel 5.4, i have checked all of my files, all of them has closing tags, or any loops or conditions are properly set but yet, i am still getting this error. what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please post full error message.

Comment: This is the full error. its in the console. @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I found a simple explanation and  solution here :  https://joelennon.com/fixing-runtimeexception-no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified-error

The reason it's happening:

> You'll often run into this when you pull down an existing Laravel application, where you copy the .env.example file to .env but don't set a value for the APP_KEY variable.

The solution is very simple you just have to run this line in your in cmd and it will set the key

```
php artisan key:generate
```

There's also an explanation in [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/encryption) website for that (in Configuration part in the page).